# How does OpenSSH determine the choose the host key algorithm?

Tags: ssh, openssh, key-authentication

After updating raspbian and all of its libraries I noticed something different about SSH. When I delete the 'known hosts' file in my home and ssh into my box it provides me with the hosts public key like always however this time I see:

```
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I swear it always gave me an RSA key type a few months back. Why did this change and how does the server decide which public key fingerprint from /etc/ssh/ to give the user connecting?

`ssh --version` on client linux mint 18 machine outputs `OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016` and host outputs `OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u3, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The client can specify the hostkey algorithm it prefers with the option HostKeyAlgorithms in `ssh_config` or `~/.ssh/config` or on the command line.  `man ssh_config` on your system to see the default HostKeyAlgorithms preference for your version of openssh.  The server will use the first key type which is on the client's list *and* exists on the server.

If you would prefer to keep the old RSA key challenge, add
"`-oHostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa`" to the command line, or add the line

```
HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa
```

to your ssh configuration file(s).