# Which host key algorithm is best to use for SSH?

Tags: ssh, encryption, openssh, key-authentication

When you first connect to an SSH server that is not contained inside your `known_hosts` file your SSH client displays the fingerprint of the public key that the server gave. I found from this question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298191/how-does-openssh-determine-the-choose-the-host-key-algorithm/298196#298196) that as a client you are able to specify within `ssh_config` which one of the public key pairs from the hosts' `/etc/ssh/` directory you would like.

From the `ssh_config` man page I found that the current defaults are as follows:

```
    ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,
    ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,
    ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,
    ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,
    ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,
    ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,
    ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,
    ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,
    ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
```

Only recently my SSH server has been sending me a ECDSA fingerprint instead of an RSA, but I was wondering which algorithm should I choose if it even matters?

[This](https://ef.gy/hardening-ssh) article claims that ECDSA is `the old elliptic-curve DSA implementation that is known to have severe vulnerabilites`
Should I be using RSA or the newest ed25519 algorithm?

Comment: I thought so, didn't know for sure though

Answer (score 1):

Currently,

- RSA is still recommended as a gold standard (strong, wide compatibility)
- ed25519 is good (independent of NIST, but not compatible with old clients.

Server is usually providing more different host key types, so you are targeting for compatibility. The order of priority in the client config is from the stronger to less strong, but more compatible.

Frankly, for you, as an end user, it does not matter. Some of the keys might have some security concerns, but none of them is considered completely broken with reasonable lengths, which could possibly cause man-in-the-middle attack or something similar.